# Can Fastify and Express run together?

Tags: express, fastify

I have an on-going http service application using Express. Recently I read Fastify and like it. I wonder if it is possible for new features I can use Fastify within the same Nodejs projects?

Thanks,
Chen

Comment: It looks to me like Fastify is its own web framework so you either use express or fastify, not both for the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of them on different ports only and work together via microservices architecture (e.g. TCP connection) or global storage (e.g. Redis)

[image]